# Create record in salesforce from java application

Tags: rest, salesforce

I need opportunity to create record in salesforce from my java application. I found out the way to receive security token, but when I try to create a record, I receive such error message in response:
 [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

It seems that I have problems with authorization, could anyone provide just a simple sample, which works. I have already tried several sets of headers, but I was not success.

Comment: Could you post relevant code ?

Comment: How are you getting the session Id that you are passing in the REST call?

Comment: I think that I missed actually some very important thing, because I didnt get session ID and user only security token...